# Was Jesus of Nazareth based on the Old Testament Jesuses?

Tags: jesus, hebrews, hebrew-bible, new-testament, gospels

Jesus (Joshua) son of Nun, kills the king of Jerusalem, hangs him on a tree, takes him down before sunset, throws the body in a cave, and rolls heavy rocks in front of the cave.
These are all NT themes related to Jesus of Nazareth (gospel Jesus)'s death.

```
Other themes from Jesus (Joshua) 10 include:
putting enemies under his feet (Hebrews, synoptics, Paul), Psalm 110:1
Adonizedek =? Melchizedek (Hebrews), Psalm 110:4 
Jesus sorta controls nature, stopping sun and moon, though he does it through God.
```

Comment: Welcome to BHSE. I was interested by your  question and have been wondering  if it could be adapted to fit this site. I hope you will persevere with us and do read the Tour to see guide lines on how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of parallels between OT history and the life of Jesus.  Indeed, many have suggested that Jesus' relived the OT history in many respects.

| OT History | Jesus’ Life |
| --- | --- |
| The progeny of Abraham that created the nation of Israel was made possible by miraculous births of Isaac & Jacob (=Israel) | Jesus’ earthly life became possible by the miraculous birth facilitated by the Holy Spirit |
| Israel is called God’s first-born son, Ex 4:22 | Jesus is Mary’s first-born son, Matt 1:25 |
| Jacob’s family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death by famine | Jesus’ family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death decree by Herod |
| Israel called out of Israel to become God’s people | Jesus; family called out of Egypt to become God’s chosen Messiah |
| Israel passes through the Red Sea equivalent to a “baptism” 1 Cor 10:2 | Jesus baptized at the beginning of His ministry |
| After passing through the Red Sea, Israel follows the cloud into the desert | After His baptism, Jesus is led by the Spirit into the desert, Matt 4:1 |
| Israel roamed for 40 years in the desert | Jesus spent 40 days fasting in the desert |
| When in the desert, Israel becomes hungry | Jesus fasted in the desert and was hungry |
| Israel healed and saved by faith when they looked at the uplifted bronze serpent | Jesus is the uplifted bronze serpent that saves by faith, John 3:14, 15 |
| Israel fed by “bread from heaven” | Jesus is the bread from heaven, John 6 |
| Israel saved by the water from the rock | Jesus is the rock, 1 Cor 10:3, 4 and is the water of life, John 4:10-14, 7:37-39 |
| Moses climbed the mountain to get the law of God | Jesus delivered his sermon of the mount (Matt 5-7) expanding the law |
| The whole ceremonial system represented Jesus as typified by the sacrificial lamb | Jesus is the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world, John 1:29 |
| The Israelites were led by a divine light, the pillar of fire | Jesus is the light of the world, John 8:12, 9:4, 5 |
| Israel began its national history with 12 tribes | Jesus began His kingdom with 12 chosen disciples |
| God used many miracles to establish the Israelite faith | Jesus used many miracles to establish the faith of disciples and Christians |
| King David captured Jerusalem and it became, “The City of David”. | Jesus “captured” Jerusalem at His triumphal entry as king is Israel, John 12:12-15. |
| God establishes a covenant with Israel in Ex 19-23 | Jesus established (or re-established) the (new) covenant |
| Israel was taken captive from the promised land and Jerusalem for their sins | Jesus was taken captive in Jerusalem for the sins of the world and taken outside the city to be crucified |
| The Jews were miraculously preserved and returned to Jerusalem after the Babylonian captivity | Jesus was miraculously resurrected from the dead and returned to Jerusalem to meet the disciples |

Even individual OT Characters often modeled parts of Jesus' life.  Here is another sample:

**Joseph**

- both are rejected by their own people
- both became servants
- both are betrayed for silver
- both are falsely accused and face false witnesses
- both attain stations at the "right hand" of the respective thrones (Joseph at Pharaoh's throne and Christ at the throne of God)
- Joseph was 30 years old when he stood before Pharaoh, and Jesus was about the same age according to the bible when he began his ministry
- Both became a Saviour to their people by going to Egypt; Joseph as a lad of 17 and Jesus as a baby (Matt 2:15)

**Miraculous Births**

Jesus’ miraculous birth was typified several times in the OT.

- Isaac came miraculously from Abraham and Sarah (Gen 18:10-14) and both are called "monogenes", Heb 11:17 and John 3:16
- Samson miraculously came from Monoa and his wife, Judges 13:2, 3 - the miraculously born Samson was Israel's deliverer
- Samuel was miraculously born to Hannah, 1 Sam 1:20. Samuel became the prophet and judge of Israel just as Jesus was
- Rachel only gave birth to Joseph after Jacob prayed. Joseph became the deliverer of Israel
- The woman in Elisha's time (2 Kings 4:14-17) miraculous gave birth. The child died and was miraculously resurrected.
- In Luke 1 we read the story of the miraculous birth of John the Baptist who became the greatest prophet

The above is part of a broader pattern of the types of Jesus in the OT such as:

- Jesus was the second Adam, Rom 5:12-18, but succeeded where Adam failed
- Jesus was the second Joshua (Jesus is the Greek form of the Hebrew Joshua) to enable Him to lead people to the heavenly promised land
- Jesus is the “Son of David” and the true king of Israel, Luke 1:23, 35, John 1:49
- Jesus is the true High Priest of (spiritual) Israel, Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22
- Jesus is the Lamb of God, John 1:29
- Jesus was the first-born (ie, most important) from the dead, Col 1:18, 1 Cor 15:12-20, Rev 1:5
- Jesus is the Firstborn (Luke 2:7, Rom 8:29, Col 1:15, Heb 1:6, 12:23) replacing Israel (Ex 4:22)

In brief, Jesus is the beginning, middle and end point of the entire Bible and its entire reason for existence.